# Vagrant up fails with VMware provider

Tags: macos, ssh, virtualbox, vmware, vagrant

When execute `vagrant up`, getting this error

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ip -o -0 addr | grep -v LOOPBACK | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://'

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:
```

OS: `13.5.1 (22G90)` 
Vagrant: `2.4.0` 
Provider: `vmware fusion 13` 
Vagrant Plugin: `vagrant-vmware-desktop (3.0.3, global)`

And Vagrantfile shows below

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "gyptazy/centos9-arm64"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"

  config.vm.network :private_network
  
  config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |v|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    v.gui = false
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
    v.vmx["memsize"] = "2048"
    v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "2"
    v.vmx["ethernet0.pcislotnumber"] = "160"
  end
end
```

For more debug info

```
DEBUG guest: Searching for cap: network_interfaces
DEBUG guest: Checking in: centos
DEBUG guest: Checking in: redhat
DEBUG guest: Checking in: linux
DEBUG guest: Found cap: network_interfaces in linux
 INFO guest: Execute capability: network_interfaces [#<Vagrant::Machine: default (HashiCorp::VagrantVMwareDesktop::Provider)>] (centos)
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: /sbin/ip -o -0 addr | grep -v LOOPBACK | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://' (sudo=true)
DEBUG ssh: stderr: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

DEBUG ssh: stderr: sudo
DEBUG ssh: stderr: :
DEBUG ssh: stderr: a password is required

DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 1
ERROR warden: Error occurred: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting. Just found this by accident. Unfortunately this is a known issue. However, it does not have any impact on the images or in the usage of these images. You can directly ssh into the box by running:

#> vagrant ssh

Cheers!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: By the way, I can not find ARM version of VMware Utility on [Install v1.0.22](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/downloads/vmware). Does it matter?